# Any order isomorphism $F$ between $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and $\mathcal{P}(B)$ W.R.T. $\subseteq$ must be $F:X\mapsto\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}$ for some $f:A\to B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I'd like to prove that if there exists an order isomorphism $F:\left\langle \mathcal{P}\left(A\right),\subseteq\right\rangle \to\left\langle \mathcal{P}\left(B\right),\subseteq\right\rangle $ for some nonempty $A$ and $B$ then there must be some $f:A\to B\ $   S.T. $F$ is defined by $F:X\mapsto\left\{ f\left(x\right)\mid x\in X\right\} $

My thought was to explicitly build $f$ out of $F$ by defining $f\left(x\right)=F\left(\left\{ x\right\} \right)$, which would work exactly as requested. However, I'm having trouble proving that $F$ must take singletons to singletons. I suspect that in general, $F$ must preserve cardinality, but I was not successful in proving this.

Comment: Wouldn't an order isomorphism $F:\mathcal P(B)\to\mathcal P(A)$ count as an "order isomorphism between $\mathcal P(A)$ and $\mathcal P(B)$"? Isn't "between" symmetric?

Comment: @bof True. What in my question suggested otherwise?

Comment: The title: "Any order isomorphism $F$ between $\mathcal P(A)$ and $\mathcal P(B)$ . . . must be . . . for some $f:A\to B$"

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Singleton sets are the minimal nonzero elements of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (and $\mathcal{P}(Y)$). Then define $f$ in such a way that $\left\{f(x)\right\}=F(\left\{x\right\})$, as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm still confused. Why does your hint imply that this is well defined? Also, I'm still curious about my hypothesis that $F$ must preserve the cardinality of all subsets

Comment: @H.Rappeport: Because singleton sets can be identified only from the structure of the order (they are exactly the elements of the order that have one and only one predecessor), the assumed order-isomorphism $F$ maps singletons to singletons. The definition of $f$ is now: Given $x$, form $\{x\}$ and apply $F$ to it. You will get a singleton in $Y$. $f(x)$ is the element of that singleton. There's nowhere in that definition "well-definedness" becomes a problem.

Comment: Once you have proved that there is an $f$ function that works, you can _then_ prove that $F$ preserves cardinailty in general (namely, the restriction of $f$ to $A\subseteq X$ is a bijection $A\to F(A)$). But it would be premature to do that without handling the singletons first.

Comment: @HenningMakholm. Understood. By "well-definedness"  I meant that given $F$, defining ${f(x)}=F({x})$ is not well defined before we have proved $F$ maps singletons to singletons. As I understand it, your insight is mainly intuitive, how would one use this to *formally* prove said property? I am posting my tentative solution, but would very much appreciate any input or more "elegant" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is clear that $F(\{x\})=\{y\}$ for some $y \in B$ otherwise if $f(\{x\})=Z=\{y_1, y_2, \cdots \}$ for surjective there exist $A \in X$ such that $f(A)=\{y_1\}$, and like $F$ is isomorphism then $A \subset \{x\}$ but $F(\emptyset)=\emptyset$. Thereforce that $f(x)=F(\{x\})$ works.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed solution:

Lemma: $F$ Takes singletons to singletons $(\forall\left\{ a\right\} \in\mathcal{P}\left(A\right)\,\,\,\exists b\in B\,\,\,F\left(\left\{ a\right\} \right)=\left\{ b\right\} )$

Proof: We are assuming $A$ and $B$ are non empty. Note that for any singleton $\left\{ a\right\} \subseteq A$ we cannot have $F\left(\left\{ a\right\} \right)=\emptyset$ since we'd get $F\left(a\right)\subseteq F\left(\emptyset\right)$ but $a\not\subseteq\emptyset$. This gives us that for $\left|A\right|=\left|B\right|=1$ the claim is immediate, so assume $\left|A\right|=\left|B\right|\geq2$. Given some singleton $\left\{ a_{1}\right\} \subset A$ we cannot have $F\left(\left\{ a_{1}\right\} \right)\geq2$ since then $F\left(\left\{ a_{1}\right\} \right)=\left\{ b_{1},b_{2}\ldots\right\}  \implies\left\{ b_{1}\right\} \subseteq F\left(\left\{ a_{1}\right\} \right)$ but $\left\{ b_{1}\right\} =F^{-1}\left(a'\right)$ for some $a'\neq a_{1}$ ($F^{-1}$ is injective) but $\left\{ a'\right\} \not\subseteq\left\{ a_{1}\right\}$

Now we are ready to define $f$. Given $a\in A\left\{ f\left(a\right)\right\} =F\left(\left\{ a\right\} \right)$

We claim $F$ must take $X\mapsto\left\{ f\left(x\right)\mid x\in X\right\}$ . This is true since otherwise either for some $\left\{ x\right\} \subseteq X$ we have $\left\{ f\left(x\right)\right\} \not\subseteq F\left(X\right)$ or for some $\left\{ f\left(x\right)\right\} \subseteq F\left(X\right)$ we have $\left\{ x\right\} \not\subseteq X$. Both of these contradicting $F$ being an isomorphism.

Comment: There are some detours here. You don't need special cases for $A$ having $0$ or $1$ element. Simply assume that you have $a\in A$ and ask yoursef what $F(\{a\})$ can be. If it is empty, then $F(\varnothing)$ and $F(\{a\})$ have the wrong relation. And if $F(\{a\})$ has at least two elements $b_1$ and $b_2$, then $\{b_1\}$ and $\{b_2\}$ both need to be images of something that is strictly smaller than $\{a\}$, but there is only one such thing, namely the empty set. This argument works no matter how many elements $A$ and $B$ themselves have.

Comment: But even that would seem to be really too detailed. The important principle is that **an isomorphism preserves every property that can be written as a logical formula that only mentions relations that this kind of isomorphism is supposed to preserve**. You need to be comfortable working directly with this principle, or you will never get full value out of your isomorphisms. In this case, "$x$ is a singleton" can be seen _within each order_ to be equivalent to $$ \exists! y : y<x $$ and _therefore_ this property is preserved by the isomorphism.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you, your input is very helpful. Especially since the context of this question is from a course in elementary set theory, where this subject is just briefly presented, meaning I wouldn't be likely to encounter these principles otherwise.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to group these insights into an answer I'd be glad to accept it.